# How to ImageView Rotate at center in 360 degree?

Tags: android, android-animation

How to rotate imageview like second stick in watch?

I want to system time get if second is 30 so image rotate in 180 degree please see my code i have implemented in thread but not start and move imageview.

thanks in adavance.

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Date date = new Date();

                            second = date.getSeconds();

                            float f = second * 6;

                            Log.e("AnimatoinView", "Second:-" + second
                                    + " Degree:-" + f);

                            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(
                                    f, 360, 36, 34);

                            mBlueCircleImageView.setAnimation(anim);

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mBlueCircleImageView.startAnimation(anim);` instead of `mBlueCircleImageView.setAnimation(anim);`